# How do I track my Wordpress hits using Google Analytics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the ANALYTICACTOR plug in to track my page hits and it seems to do exactly what it needs to be doing, it places its code on every page. What I want to know is , is there something wrong with the code below or could I have my account set up wrong because it either has to be this code or my account settings are not correct. Google did track eight hits to my website at one point and now I do not know why it has stopped doing so. Any help would be appreciated and I will email you an original screenplay if things go well, ill even email you a screenplay if you just try becuse I write i cant code.

my website with the fully html code is at http://www.knowledgenation.us

var analyticsFileTypes = [''];
    var analyticsEventTracking = 'enabled';



    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21764875-1']);
    pub-4733510614502996


    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

Comment: A quick way to verify the GA code is loading successfully (and tracking data is sent) is via the network tab in your browser console.  With ga.js, look for a request to www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif -- if you don't see the request, then the ga.js file isn't loading successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your page actually has two calls to Google Analytics. There's another one at the bottom of the page that sends data to the `UA-23607774-1` account. That's working correctly and sending data but the code snippet you've posted above is reporting an error and not tracking properly. The line with `pub-4733510614502996` is the problem and needs to be removed. I'm guessing it's located in the `Additional tracking code (before tracker initialization)` field of the Google Analyticator settings.

Comment: im sorry i am most definitely slow at this ... i just disabled the code that places the google analytics code at the top of the page and now all that is left is the code that you spoke of at the bottom of the page. i might have always had two pieces of code working this entire time because it has not been working for some time. <br> I appreciate your help. I am going to assume that the code will be working now that i took out the analytics plug in. <br> how did you know that UA-23607774-1 was working correctly? Did you use tools? How did you arrive at your conclusion?